# Probability of an event with tossing a die 3 times

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

One tosses a die three times. We denote the obtained result by
$(X, Y , Z)$.

> $X \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}.$
> $Y \in\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}.$
> $Z \in\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}.$

We define the event
$A = \text{“}X\leq 4$ and $Y\leq 4$ and $Z \leq 4$ and $X \neq Y \neq Z\text{”}$

> Find $P(A)$.

I know the answer but I don't know how to get it.

> $P(A)= 1/9$ with order
>
> $P(A) = 4/56$ without order

It is about arrangement, permutation and combination.

I tried

> $P(A)=3\times2\times1/6^3=1/36$

Can someone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: How may ways are there to choose three distinct numbers $≤ 4$? How many ways to order these? How many ways can you throw three dice?

Comment: Note:  I don't understand the bit about "with order" or "without order".  $A$ is defined the way it is.  What is it that you are ordering?

Comment: the order counts and the order doesn't count. Permutation and combination

Comment: That does not make sense.  If you are defining two different events, please define each of them separately.

Comment: @alisonmonroe The order of what?

Comment: What is meant by $X\neq Y\neq Z$? That $X\neq Y\wedge Y\neq Z$ or that $\{X,Y,Z\}$ has cardinality $3$?

Comment: is the answer given as 4/56, not 1/14?

Comment: Judging by the desired answer, the first question should read "What is the probability that if a six-sided die is tossed three times that three different outcomes are obtained and each outcome is at most $4$?"  The second question is problematic since the $56$ events in the sample space are not equally likely to occur.

Comment: I start to doubt the second answer too. I will propose another answer

Comment: The first question is not stated properly.  Saying $X \neq Y \neq Z$ does not mean that there are three different outcomes.  It means $X \neq Y$ and $Y \neq Z$, so $X = 1$, $Y = 3$, and $Z = 1$ is a permissible outcome under the formulation $X \neq Y \neq Z$.  Judging by the desired answer, what you meant is that when a die is tossed three times, three different outcomes occur and each of those outcomes is at most $4$.

Answer (score 3):

Like I mentioned the question is about arrangement and combination.

With order it is an arrangement;

Blockquote

$P(A)= \frac{Favorable Event}{All Possible Event}$

$P(A)= \frac{\frac{4!}{(4-3)!}}{6^3}= \frac{24}{216} =\frac{1}{9}$

Without order it is a combination;

$P(A)= \frac{\frac{4!}{(4-3)!*3!}}{6^3}= \frac{4}{216} =\frac{1}{54}$

Comment: So with "order" you are talking about $X<Y<Z$ (or $X>Y>Z$)? Clarification of that was requested in several comments on your question. We really could not know this.

Answer (score 2):

With order there are $6^3$ total outcomes.

Again in order, there are $4 \times 3 \times 2$ options, assuming you mean to say that $X,Y$ and $Z$ are all different from each other. Namely $4$ options for the first , $3$ for the second (as we must pick among $\{1,2,3,4\}$ minus the first value), and finally $2$ for $Z$.

In the ordered case the answer is $$\frac{4 \times 3 \times 2}{6 ^3} = \frac{4}{36} = \frac{1}{9}$$

as asked for.

I have no good idea about how you'd interpret "unordered" here ;the way it's formulated it's ordered by definition; I could add more if you would explain it better.

Comment: Judging by the desired answer, the question should read "What is the probability that if a six-sided die is tossed three times that three different outcomes are obtained and no outcome exceeds $4$?"

Answer (score 2):

Let $E$ denote the event $X\neq Y\neq Z$ (this notation is unclear because $\neq$ is not a transitive relation).

Then $$P(A)=P(E\wedge \max(X,Y,Z)\leq4)=P(E\mid\max(X,Y,Z)\leq4)P(\max(X,Y,Z)\leq4)=$$$$P(E\mid\max(X,Y,Z)\leq4)\times\left(\frac46\right)^3$$

If $E$ is the event that $X,Y,Z$ take distinct values then $P(E\mid\max(X,Y,Z)\leq4)=\frac44\frac34\frac24$.

If $E$ is the event that $X\neq Y\wedge Y\neq Z$ then $P(E\mid\max(X,Y,Z)\leq4)=\frac44\frac34\frac34$.

Answer (score 1):

For part 1, we can have the patterns

$$123,124,132,134,142,143$$

and repeat for X=2,3,4 for a total of $24$ positive outcomes.

There are $216$ outcomes in total, and $\frac{24}{216}=\frac19$.